# React.render not rendering element to DOM

Tags: reactjs

If I execute the following code it works.

```js
var Add = React.createClass({
  render:function () {
    var sum = this.props.x + this.props.y;
    return React.DOM.span({}, sum);
  }
});

Add = React.createFactory(Add);

var element = Add({ x: 2, y: 3 }); // <span>5</span>

React.render(element,document.body);
```

But If I combine the top code with the following code.  React.Render isn't displaying the value of Double.  I am probably missing something but not sure what.

```js
var Add = React.createClass({
  render:function () {
    var sum = this.props.x + this.props.y;
    return React.DOM.span({}, sum);
  }
});

Add = React.createFactory(Add);

var Double = React.createClass({
  render:function () {
    return React.createElement(Add({
      x: this.props.value,
      y: this.props.value
    }));
  }
});

Double = React.createFactory(Double);
var element = Double({ value: 2 });

React.render(element,document.body);  //Should output <span>4</span>
```

Comment: Neither of your code snippets are working.  I would suggest adding them to the a jsfiddle.  Additionally, why are you trying to create components this way?  This is a very awkward way to use React, and I wouldn't suggest using doing it this way unless you had a really compelling reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your `render` function for `Double`, you're passing `Add` to `React.createElement` unnecessarily; you've already wrapped it with `React.createFactory`. Try:

```
var Double = React.createClass({
 render:function () {
   return Add({
     x: this.props.value,
     y: this.props.value
    });
  }
});
```

See: https://jsbin.com/cacese/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your solution is very clear and removes redundancy.   Currently I am just going thru the tutorials I signed up for in Reactweek Online.  Pretty good course but probably dated now.